# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de pasar argumentos a funciones?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Estaba preparando una serie de funciones para *Excel* y me estoy encontrando con problemas de sintaxis. Y por más que estoy buscando información al respecto, solo encuentro ejemplos sencillos que no dan respuesta a mi duda.

#### Contexto

Una de las funciones, copia una hoja varias veces asignando a cada una un nombre dentro del bucle.

```
' La función no es completa, es solo 
' para que sirva de contexto en como
' intento usar la otra función en el if
'
Function CopySheets(Num As Integer)

    Dim nameSheet As String

    For i = 1 To Num

        ' Set del nombre de la hoja
        nameSheet = "mes " & i

        If SheetExist nameSheet Then
            ' si existe
        Else
            ' si no existe
        End If


    Next i       

End Function
```

La función *SheetExist* admite como argumento un *string* con el nombre de la hoja y retorna un `True` o `False`.

#### Problema

El problema que encuentro es de sintaxis, no es un código con el que estoy familiarizado, y no he encontrado como pasar argumentos dentro de un `If`.

He probado:

```
If SheetExist nameSheet Then
'...

If SheetExist(nameSheet) Then
'...

exist = SheetExist nameSheet
If exist Then
'...
```

Y algunas formas más, todas con resultado erróneo.

#### Pregunta

> ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de pasar argumentos a funciones cuando forman parte de una sentencia `If`?

Comment: La segunda forma es la correcta por lo que no se me ocurre en principio por qué te está dando error, ¿podrías poner los mensaje de error que te devuelve y la declaración de SheetExist?

Comment: @RobertoVaccaro pues es bastante extraño. El error lanzado era _Error de compilación: Error de sintaxis_. He vuelto a probar la segunda opción como has indicado y ahora si realiza el proceso correctamente. No había cambiado nada más, así que no puedo entender que estaba pasando si estaba correcto. Publícalo como respuesta y la acepto. Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende de la situación. Esto se aplica tanto a procedimientos de evento como a funciones.

Respuesta simple: si ejecutas un procedimiento/función solamente, no necesitas que los argumentos vayan entre paréntesis. Pero si lo combinas con otra orden, comando o similar, entonces **sí es obligatorio** escribir los argumentos entre paréntesis.

Pongamos un ejemplo sencillo. Yo tengo este procedimiento definido en un módulo:

```
Sub SALUDO(ByVal NombrePersona As String)
    MsgBox "Buenas noches, " & NombrePersona
End Sub
```

Lo ejecutamos desde otro procedimiento:

```
Sub pruebas()
 SALUDO "Elier"
End Sub
```

Si ejecuto el procedimiento anterior, se ejecuta sin problemas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora modifiquemos el Sub que hemos llamado *pruebas*, de la siguiente manera. Llamemos al Sub *Saludo* con el comando **[Call](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/call-statement)**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El editor de VBA da error. Aquí sí se nos exige separar los argumentos de cada comando/procedimiento/función con paréntesis. La manera correcta de escribirlo sería así:

```
Sub pruebas()
 Call SALUDO("Elier")
End Sub
```

Es decir, el propio editor de VBA obliga a meter los argumentos del Sub *SALUDO* entre paréntesis, para poder leer el código correctamente.

La razón exacta y técnica de por qué es así no la conozco. Pero supongo que será para poder separar los argumentos correctamente de cada comando/procedimiento/función. Es decir, al meter entre paréntesis los argumentos del Sub *SALUDO*, permite a VBA leer el código sin errores ni equivocaciones.

Así que, respondiento a tu pregunta, la forma correcta de pasar argumentos a funciones es:

1. Si en la sintaxis no hay ningún otro comando/procedimiento/función, **los argumentos van sin paréntesis**.
2. Si lo combinamos con otro comando/procedmiento/función o cuando queremos guardar el valor dentro de una variable, entonces **los argumentos deben ir entre paréntesis.**

Puedes profundizar más sobre el tema en algunos enlaces si quieres. Siento que mi respuesta sea poco profesional, pero espero que pueda ayudar un poco.

> [Llamada a los procedimientos Sub y
>   Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/calling-sub-and-function-procedures)
>
> [When to Use Parentheses with a Subroutine or Function in
>   VB/VBA/VBScript.](http://www.devguru.com/content/features/kb/kb100222.html)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Me ha quedado claro que reglas hay para usar paréntesis o no.